# What VPN Device should I get to hide my http traffic

Tags: server

I want to set up a VPN network: client + server because i'm often connected to unsecured wifi network.

-When the client is connected, all HTTP / HTTPS traffic must pass through the VPN
-The client can be software (openVNP) or hardware (router)
-The server must be a device purchased and specially designed for this purpose without any firmware modification.

For the client, I will use OpenVPN as beginning (later a router as clientVPN). And for the server I thought of this: https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-LRT214/

What do you think about the server ? Any advice is welcome.

Note: i'm working under windows

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your client + server idea is. Are you saying that you want all traffic on a certain network to pass through a VPN? If so, why would the client have to connect to the server? Why would it matter what the client is?

Comment: For "The server must be a device purchased and specially designed for this purpose without any firmware modification.", why? Does this include simply loading an OS (no firmware changes)? What about building your own box? What are you size/budget limitations?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but what I want is to secure all my HTTP traffic with the constraint of not renting services to a third company/website. So any device must be physically at my home. I need something very simple (as much as possible). My budget limitation for this is 500 euros

Comment: Okay I think I see: you want a server that you own to be somewhere else, and then you tunnel all your traffic through that server?

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want ...

Comment: [Take a look at sshuttle](https://superuser.com/questions/62303/how-can-i-tunnel-all-of-my-network-traffic-through-ssh)